# How to use setPaintFlags - xamarin, android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, textbox, xamarin.android

I want to set `UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG` effect on my `TextView` in Xamarin, but receive an error

> TextView does not contain definition of setPaintFlag

Here is my code:

```
   using Android.App;using Android.Widget;
   using Android.OS;
   using Android.Graphics;
   using System.Net;
   using HtmlAgilityPack;

   namespace test
   {
       [Activity(Label = "test", MainLauncher = true)]
       public class MainActivity : Activity
       {
           protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
           {
               base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
               SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);


               TextView productNameText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
               productNameText.Text= productName;
    //this code not working
                productNameText.setPaintFlags(productNameText.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
          }   
      }

   }
```

Do I have to add a missing reference (`using ?`)? I cannot find a solution.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and Xamarin.

Comment: I have info about "TextView dosnt contain definition of setPaintFlag" what i have to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the TextView [PaintFlags](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Widget.TextView.PaintFlags/) property

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is so simple!